# Why APT wants to upgrade already up to date package?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dpkg

Package version `1.14.2-2+deb10u1` is installed and `1.14.2-2+deb10u1` is the latest version in the repository at time of writing.

```
dpkg -l | grep nginx-extras ii  nginx-extras
```

> 1.14.2-2+deb10u1                                                  amd64        nginx web/proxy server (extended version)

```
apt update

apt dist-upgrade --simulate

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nginx-extras
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst nginx-extras [1.14.2-2+deb10u1] (1.14.2-2+deb10u1 Debian:10.3/stable, Debian-Security:10/stable [amd64])
Conf nginx-extras (1.14.2-2+deb10u1 Debian:10.3/stable, Debian-Security:10/stable [amd64])
```

Yet, APT wants to upgrade. Why? How can I let APT know that the system is already upgraded?

Why not just do the upgrade? I don't want to needlessly upgrade using APT. Because that would overwrite my local changes.

Background:

I manually downloaded (`apt source nginx-extras`), compiled, made local changes, installed the package[s] using dpkg and apt. The package source folder debian/changelog matches [web repository repository changelog file](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/n/nginx/nginx_1.14.2-2+deb10u1_changelog).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your installed package doesn’t match the packages available from the repositories, even though they have the same versions. (As [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) figured out, this appears to be based on the installed size of the package: if the installed package’s version is identical to that available from the repositories, but its installed size is different, `apt` will want to replace the package with the version available from the repositories. The installed size is listed in `Packages` for remote packages, and `/var/lib/dpkg/status` for installed packages. All this of course is also subservient to package pin priorities.)

Whenever you build a package locally, especially if you make changes to it, it’s a good idea to update the changelog as if you were doing a non-maintainer upload:

```
dch -n "Summary of your changes"
dch -r ignored
```

That way `apt` won’t try to replace your package with the packages in the repositories, until the latter are updated.